# Compress Files from list with PowerShell 5

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I have a file with a list of files with directions.

Like this:

```
XXXXXX/sample.txt

XXXXXX/dog.txt

XXXXXX/cat.docx

ZZZZ/lamp.jpg
```

How can I to compress all files and save files with sub-directions.

Now, I can to compress all files but without directions.

Like this:

```
sample.txt

dog.txt

cat.docx

lamp.jpg
```

Sorry on my bad English.

Answer (score 4):

```
foreach ($filename in Get-Content .\ListOfFilesToZip.txt)
{
    Compress-Archive -Update $filename .\ZipFile.zip
}
```

Comment: explanations along with the code are usually helpful

Answer (score 1):

The following function can compresses a whole folder structure into a single zip file and will keep the structure within the zip (even works with PowerShell <5).

```
function createZipFile($outputFileName, $sourceDirectory){
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem
    $compressionLevel = [System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel]::Optimal
    [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory($sourceDirectory, $outputFileName, $compressionLevel, $false)
}
```

Call it like that:

```
createZipFile "c:\temp\output.zip" "c:\folder\to\compress"
```

Comment: Or you could just use `Compress-Archive` since he's on PSv5.  But this doesn't answer the question since he's trying to selectively grab files from a directory while also grabbing that directory.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit If question is about getting filename from the path**
The most efficient way would be with a regex, but they can be rather complicated if you are not used to working with them.

A simpler way would be to simply split each string and select the last part where the file name is:

```
$string = "c:\asd\qwe\zxc\dog.txt"

#Split the string on each \
    $string.Split("\") 

#This will output a list like this
c:
asd
qwe
zxc
dog.txt
```

Now we want to simply select the last entry in this list as the filename is always last in a path. So we use Select Object for that.

```
$string.Split("\") | Select-Object -Last 1
```

This will return:

```
dog.txt
```

You can run this through a foreach on your list to get it for each item.

Comment: I believe he's looking for a way to compress a list of files while retaining the folder structure

Comment: Thanks, but I need to save the folder structure.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there's any better way of doing this, but you can create a temp folder, copy the files to be archived along with desired folder structure over there and then just zip up the whole thing.

Take a look [here](https://www.petri.com/custom-archiving-powershell-5-0) (not my code, but seems to do exactly that) for a sample

Comment: Thank you! It's like what I need. I see haven't easy way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
function DirNewTemp {
    $tmpdir = (New-TemporaryFile).FullName
    Remove-Item -Force -Path $tmpdir -ErrorAction 'SilentlyContinue'
    New-Item -Type Directory $tmpdir | out-null
    return $tmpdir
}

function ZipFiles {
    param(
        [string]$Zip,
        [string[]]$FileList
    )
    write-host ""
    write-host "====================================="
    write-host "ZipFile $Zip"
    write-host "====================================="
    
    $pwd      = (Get-Location).Path     
    $tmpdir   = DirNewTemp
        
    try {
        $count = $FileList.Count
        foreach ($file in $FileList) {
            $pwd_escaped = [Regex]::Escape($pwd)        
            $save_file   = $file -replace "^${pwd_escaped}\\", "${tmpdir}\"
            $save_path   = Split-Path $save_file -Parent
            New-Item  -Force -Path $save_path -ItemType Directory | out-null
            Copy-Item -Force $file $save_file           
        }
        set-location $tmpdir        
        $dest = "$pwd\$Zip";
        write-host "Creating Zip: $dest"        
        Compress-Archive -Force -Path * -DestinationPath $dest
    }
    finally {
        write-host "cleanup"
        set-location $pwd
        remove-item -Force -Recurse -Path $tmpdir -ErrorAction 'SilentlyContinue'
    }
}
```